# C# RichTextBox colored text

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, textcolor

I've a RichTextBox and I want color text in it. Is there any tag option? I'd like something like this `[color:red]nick[/color] some message`. Because I need to save it as text and I want on reload have also colored text.

Can I do something like this without writing own method?

Answer (score 7):

You can set color for text in RichTextBox with [`SelectionColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectioncolor.aspx)

And if you want to save your rtf as plain text, then you will have to look at rtf [format](http://www.pindari.com/rtf1.html).   Example:

> {\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;}
>   This line is the default color\line \cf2 This line is red\line \cf1
>   This line is the default color }

**EDIT:**

From this example - first of all you have to declare color table `\colortbl` in fololowing format:

```
{\colortbl; color1; color2; ... ; colorN;}
```

And then in the text you will have to enclose text with `{\cfN YOUR_TEXT}` where N is a number of color from table; you can not specify the boundaries of the block {}, then everything after \ cfN will be one color.

Comment: I'd like some easy way do that this -> [color:red]red text[/color] will be after calling some method just red text. I don't know how can I replace these tags and select the text between them and use on it selection color.

Comment: The easiest way would be saving your text in rtf format. Is it an option for you?

Comment: I don't know if it's good way. I'd like save a long conversations and rtf format is long I don't want have so big files. I think that use regular expresions to get the color from tag retype it to `Color` get position of ] and [ so I can select text between and sipmply set SelectionColor. I know that everythink but I don't know Regex and methods to work with string as I want and thats cause I ask here.

Comment: In my opinion, it would be much more problems and unnecessary coding, if you will focus on processing plain text. And it will be two way procesing - you will have to read plain text and make it colourfull anf then you will have to read rtf and make it tagged text. I do not think, that rtf is that big :) And if you want - learn regexp in the side project, for the beggining http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Comment: Thanks for link I'll check it. This line is only needed on the top of file so only once? {\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;} If yes I'll use it. Cause I though that I shoud have it on every line and thats probably nonsense.

Comment: Updated my answer with better explanations

Answer (score 3):

As the name says RichTextBox contains RichText

to change the Rtf text with 'rtf specific-tags' you can set/use the

[RichTextBox.RtfProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf)

also take a look at [RichTextBox.SelectionColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectioncolor.aspx) to color text patterns in code

but when you don't want to use rtf, you said

> need to save as text.

you could write your own 'markup' there is no built in expect rtf/html?

but **rtf is text** - at all

Example to use RichTextBix.SelectionColor to Color the text

```
richTextBox1.Text = "Hello";
richTextBox1.Select(0,2);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

colors the start of "Hello" red
and now you can access the 'taggeg' text in the RTFProperty of the RichTextBox

Answer (score 0):

If you need examples of how things are encoded in RTF, you can create the document manually in Word or Wordpad, and save it as RTF. This will give you a hint about how to encode your formatting. Furthermore, if you're for instance creating help-documents, you can include them as an embedded resource and load them directly into the RichTextBox, with all the formatting included.

Answer (score -1):

```
rtfMain.SaveFile(dlgSave.FileName);
```

From Reference [Save text from rich text box with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751929/save-text-from-rich-text-box-with-c-sharp)