# Can i change a cretin string color?

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, textbox

if want to change a word from the string below whats the code i should use ?

```
 Private Sub Button 1_Click(sender As Object, e As Event Args) Handles Button 1.Click
 text box 1.text = "How are you"
 end sub
```

can i change just the word (you) color to green ?

i tried this but it gives me errors

```
Private Sub Button 1_Click(sender As Object, e As Event Args) Handles Button 1.Click
 text box 1.text = "How are" ("you"). fore color .green
 end sub
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this using the control: RichTextBox

see post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12191654/2356484