# Created txt file using c# but created file escapes the new line?

Tags: c#, text-files, filestream

After it's created the text file but it's escaping the "new line" in richtextbox that i am adding tell me how to fix that + when creating file with big name and huge amount of data it's giving exception.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Saver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
    string path = "";

    public MainForm()
    {
        //
        // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer            
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        //
        // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
        //
    }

    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if((textBox1.Text != "")&&(richTextBox1.Text != ""))
        {
            if(radioButton1.Checked == true)
                path = @"C:\Users\M.Waqas\Desktop\Saver\Saver\Files\";

            path += textBox1.Text + ".txt";

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Create);
            StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(fs);
            wr.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Your file create on :" + "\n" + path);
            textBox1.Clear();
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            wr.Close();
            fs.Close();


        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Which exception and at which line?

Comment: I would recommend wrapping that code in a Try{}catch{} and that FileStream code wrap that around a `using()` clause, also when you debug the code .. which I am sure you haven't what do you get..? what like are you erroring on..?

Comment: exception coming when making big file name and big content and i complited it already and it was working fine. And basic issue is my code is escaping new line which i enter in richtextbox on runtime after created the file and if possible can you give the correct code after fix on your end?

Comment: Poor question, poor code, probably needs Homework tag.
Use (learn about) try/catch and debug.writeline(exceptionCaught). Use `using` because this code can keep giving you file-in-use exceptions if it fails once. Use Path.Combine for file name.

Comment: @Sten Petrov: basically i am beginner can you please make this code ok? i need this thing to be done thanks

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751929/save-text-from-rich-text-box-with-c-sharp

Comment: -1 You need things to be done.. then perhaps you need to start doing that ..stop relying on others to do your work for you.. beginner or not.. there are `1000a` of examples on line .. I would suggest you try them and step thru the example code and learn what each line in the example is doing..otherwise I would suggest taking a new career path

Answer (score 2):

How about using .NET methods instead of rewriting them?

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      try{
           if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBox1.Text))
           {
                if(radioButton1.Checked) 
                     path = @"C:\Users\M.Waqas\Desktop\Saver\Saver\Files\"; 

                path = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, textBox1.Text  ".txt");

                richTextBox1.SaveFile(path);  

           } else
                MessageBox.Show("No data");

      } catch (Exception x){
           MessageBox.Show("Error: "+x);
      }
}
```

NOTE: path was copied over from OP, SaveFileDialog should be used instead of hard-coded paths (even worse - user-related hard-coded paths). The path code may be incomplete for the case the radiobutton is unchecked.

Comment: wow this answer is just as messing as the OP's original posting I would suggest formatting that answer to make it more readable

Comment: @DJKRAZE true that, I hope the edit made it better.

Comment: +2 much better Sten Pertrov